# Unable to import from pixellib.tune_bg. I have here workiing on collab notebook

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I am here working in collab notebook

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.tune_bg import alter_bg
```

this is code i am writing and this is the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/**init**.py)

i tried differnt versions of tensorflow.